# wsgi_mod dosn't serve admin static files

Tags: django, mod-wsgi

I know that there is few topic with this problem, but I still cannot resolve it. I have this structure

```
/home
  /server
    /server_1
      /static
```

Static was generated by collectstatic and I have there all my staticfiles (include admin/css)

Alias for static files in apach conifg look like:

```
Alias /static/ /home/server/server_1/static/
<Directory /home/server/server_1/static/>
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

When I'm running django admin page I can see login panel but without css but If i I click 'show page source' I can see

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/base.css" />
```

And I can click, and I can see whole css code (no 404 error) So, server can see this file? But it can use it or what?

When I'm trying open:

```
http://www.my.server.com/static/
```

I'm getting

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /static/ on this server.
```

I have STATIC_ROOT, and STATIC_URL, I can correctly run collectstatif, but server has some problem with render it.

**EDIT**

I've just installed django-rest-framework and this server and same situation with css. Css files are in serveradres.com/static/, I can access to it by redirect serveradres.com/static/rest_framework/css/bootstrap.min.css

But site still render page without this css.

**UPDATE**

Google chrome inspector saying:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

Comment: What version of Apache and mod_wsgi are you on? That's an Apache 2.4+ declaration you're using. If you're on an earlier version the syntax is different.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if this is it, but try losing the trailing slash on your Directory directive: `<Directory /home/server/server_1/static/>` should be `<Directory /home/server/server_1/static>`.

Comment: I've tried without this slash - same error. I have apache 3.4 and 4.3 wsgi

Comment: 3.4 is your Python version; what about your Apache version? `apachectl -V`

Comment: apache 2.4 missed key, sorry. Python is 3.5

Answer (score 1):

The user that Apache runs as can't see inside home directories with the permissions that are usually set on home directories by a Linux system. It is recommended you move your application code outside of your home directory to somewhere the Apache user can see.

Comment: Can't set permisions for that? So why I can see css cod by redirect? I have access to this file by browser.

Comment: Don't know what you mean by "Can't set permissions for that". I never said to change permissions on anything. If your home directory for ``/home/server`` has already had its permissions changed to ``o+rx`` so Apache can see inside it, then the reason you would get forbidden on the top level directory is because Apache disables directory browsing by default. You have to enable it, although not recommended. See ``Options Indexes`` in http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options

Comment: Ok, I don't want to enable this. But that was a secondary 'problem' I still don't understand why my site is rendering without css, but I can access them via browser. Please, see the edit.

Comment: Have you checked the HTML returned to ensure it is giving back the correct URL path for style sheets etc.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. I know - this is strange, but it was caused by an adblock in google chrom. When I turn it off, it works.